# How do I take an integer from a list intending to use it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from collections import Counter
data = Counter(landedonspaces)
newdata = data.most_common()   # Returns all unique items and their counts
print newdata
one = [e[1] for e in newdata if e[0] == 1]
```

`landedonspaces` is a list of random numbers from 1 to 40. 
I have defined one, and it is a list comprehension, going through the list which is newdata. Defined above, the newdata gives a list with each random number and how many times it occurs in the list. E.g., the list would be like `[(1, 234), (5, 123),....]`. So the list comprehension goes through this list, and gives the second value of each duplet only if the first value is 1.
What I want to do then is take the number and use it in calculations. More specifically I want to take this number and devide another number by it. However when I do this it is still in the form of a list as you would expect.
So how do I take the integer from the list?

Comment: make `newdata = dict(data.most_common()` then access the number with `newdata[1]`

Comment: actually now that I think about it, you could just do that with your original `Counter` object....

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do thank you! Not sure what you mean by using the counter object though

Comment: you should be able to just do `data[1]` since `Counter` is a `dict`-like object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of numbers:

```
>>> one = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

you can access them via index, starting with `0`:

```
>>> one[0]
1
>>> one[2]
2
```

the last one:

```
>>> one[-1]
4
```

You can calculate with them:

```
>>> one[1] + one[1]
4
```

or store under a different name:

```
>>> a = one[1]
>>> a
2
>>> a + a
4
```